# moodle : how to get user id from forgot password page?

Tags: php, mysql, moodle

Is there any option to get `$USER-id` data from **set_password_form.php** page. Fortunately it working in **change_password_form.php** page when use this code.

```
global $USER, $CFG;
$result = $DB->get_record_sql("SELECT * FROM {user} WHERE id = ?", array($USER->id));
```

But unfortunately this method doesn't work in reset password page. 
Does anybody have idea how to get the user id from reset password page ?

**Update:-**

`global $USER` not giving any user details.

Comment: Which version of Moodle are you using? I can't see a file called set_password_form.php in Moodle 2.5 - is this in the /login/ folder?

Comment: @RussellEngland I am on 2.5

Comment: Yeah, there isn't a set_password_form.php in Moodle 2.5 - https://github.com/moodle/moodle/tree/MOODLE_25_STABLE/login - if you are using git then do a git blame login/set_password_form.php - it might be custom?

Comment: @RussellEngland I thinks so

Comment: On the reset password page, isn't the user **NOT** logged in?. Why would there be a userid available at that point?

Comment: @KevinB Thank for your response. That is what I am trying now, there is hidden username input text in the page I can see

Comment: sounds kinda fishy. What do you need the userid for?

Comment: @KevinB use `QUERY` in **username* table to grab user details :)

Comment: User details for what user? the user isn't logged in. If you're displaying the user details of a user that isn't logged in yet, you're leaking the user's personal information to potentially malicious users.

Comment: Can you post the content of set_password_form.php - global $USER should be available inside the form.